# Remove border on JTable header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` attached to a `JScrollPane` by `JScrollPane.setRowHeaderView(JTable)`.
Looking like this:

[image]

But I would like to remove the border(3d effect) around the line number table:

[image]

It is to thick. Any ideas how to remove it?

```
public class SimpleJTableHeader extends JFrame {

    public JTable table;

    public SimpleJTableHeader() {

        // CREATE A JTABLE
        Object rowData[][] = { { "a" }, { "b" }, { "c" }, { "d" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "1" };
        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // ADD ROW NUMBERS TO THE TABLE
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(getHeaderTable());

        // SHOW TABLE
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTable getHeaderTable() {
        final AbstractTableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return table.getRowCount();
            }
        };
        JTable headerTable = new JTable(model);
        headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(40, 0));
        headerTable.setRowHeight(20);
        headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                component.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
                return component;
            }
        });
        return headerTable;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SimpleJTableHeader();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the component returned by [getTableCellRendererComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29) call as [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and then set the border as you wish:

```
    headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JComponent component = (JComponent)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
            component.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
            component.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            return component;
        }
    });
```

In any case you may want to take a look to Rob Camick's [RowNumberTable](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) great example.